# How to call a method when an attribute is written

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I want to call a method when an attribute of an object is written. For example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def isAdult(self):
        print(True if self.age>=21 else False)
```

If i want to call `.isAdult()` when an object's `age` is written a value, how can I achieve this?

I heard of people suggesting to use decorators, but they didn't give more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to have is called a [`setter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#property). You must use new-style classes and extend `object` to use them:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self._age = age

    def isAdult(self):
        print(self.age >= 21)

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, value):
        self._age = value
        self.isAdult()
```

Then, for example:

```
p = Person("John Doe", 12)
p.age = 16
p.age = 25
```

will print

```
False
True
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use decorator in class like below.

In below code, isAdultDeco will be call when you create Person object.

```py
class Person:
    def isAdultDeco(func):
        def foo(self, name, age):
            func(self, name, age)
            print(True if self.age>=21 else False)
        return foo


    @isAdultDeco
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

Person('a',22) # True
Person('a',20) # False
```

Comment: This will only trigger on object initialisation, though. It won't fire up _"when an object's age is written a value"_ as specified in the question.